# Change R BLAS library path

Tags: linux, r, bash

Currently the R on my system using this library for `BLAS':

```
ldd /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf
```

I want to change the path to use ACML.

Is it possible to change the path? For example by setting an enviroment in `.bashrc` or `.Rprofile`.

Th ACML path is:

```
/opt/acml4.4.0/gfortran64_mp/lib/libacml_mp.so
```

I do not have the root password.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick), for example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/other/blas/lib/libacml_mp.so R
```

That will run R with a modified `LD_PRELOAD` which will force loading of your other BLAS shared library files.  You can put it in your `~/.bashrc` as an alias:

```
alias R='LD_PRELOAD=/other/blas/lib/libacml_mp.so R'
```

Comment: Thanks. The ACML library name is`libacml_mp.so`. How can I set that?

Comment: @user1436187: I've updated my answer to work with a totally different shared library name such as you have.

Comment: I used this command ` LD_PRELOAD='/opt/acml4.4.0/gfortran64_mp/lib/libacml_mp.so' R` and I get this error: `/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libacml_mv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Note: The `libacml_mv.so` is in the `/opt/acml4.4.0/gfortran64_mp/lib/` directory.

Comment: How does R know that it must change libblas.so.3gf. R linked to several libraries.

Comment: You probably need to add `libacml_mv.so` to your `LD_PRELOAD` as well, e.g. `LD_PRELOAD="/other/blas/lib/libacml_mv.so /other/blas/lib/libacml_mp.so" R`.